# There is an API to set the minimum number of milliseconds that may occur between the first and second clicks of a double-click?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, winapi

I've found the function [SetDoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which sets the double-click time for the mouse.

this means: `the maximum number of milliseconds that may occur between the first and second clicks of a double-click.`

But I would like to set in the OS the opposite thing, the minimum interval to consider that the user made a double-click.

This is possible to do?

**EDIT:** Just I would like to know if I have more alternatives than hooking the mouse and setting a timer or something else to compare the times.

> UPDATE

My initial intention was to think in ways to translate this `AutoHotkey` snippet to `.NET` code:

```
LButton:: If ( A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 50 ) 
SendInput, {Lbutton Down} 
return 
Lbutton Up::SendInput, {Lbutton Up} 

MButton:: If ( A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 50 ) 
SendInput, {MButton Down} 
return 
Mbutton Up::SendInput, {MButton Up} 

RButton:: If ( A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 50 ) 
Sendinput, {Rbutton Down} 
return 
Rbutton Up::SendInput, {Rbutton Up}
```

I just supposed that maybe I could save all the time for writting a code by using a native function from Windows API.

Comment: Are you helping the user configure the system-wide setting, or do you want to change the double-click behavior in your program?  If the user hasn't asked you to change the system behavior, changing the system-wide setting would be very impolite.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure there is no minimum.  Why should there be?

Comment: Judging by the settings in Control Panel, I'm going to say no (the lack of such of a function on MSDN also gives a hint). One wonders what the utility of such a function would be, which would provide a reason to the seeming lack of said function.

Comment: @Ben Voigt the user in this case is only me, sorry for don't explained it in full detail, I would like to change this value in my system (only in my system)

Comment: @Grant Winney The reason could be the typical defective mouse that performs unintentionally double-clicks in a very short time

Comment: *The default maximum is 500msec*. Anything bellow that is considered *double-click*

Comment: Thanks for your comments everybody, the reasoning for say "NO" is reasonable and convincent but if someone could give proofs (I mean official references or something like that) explaining that a "default minimum interval" can't be set in the system then I really would like to know it and accept an answer like that. while this information couldn't be confirmed maybe could exists a "hidden" trick that maybe we could don't know, is not the first time that I've seen two related functions in the MSDN which are not in the same reference section (for example, to give a hope), thanks again

Comment: Proving a negative is usually impossible. I've been programming Windows for 15 years and have never come across an official way to do this.

Comment: @ElektroStudios The solution to a defective mouse is to either fix it or send it to recycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function reads and writes all the double-click parameters.

There are three.  `SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME` is the same parameter set by `SetDoubleClickTime`; `SPI_SETDOUBLECLKHEIGHT` and `SPI_SETDOUBLECLKWIDTH` define the size of the rectangle the second click must fall within.

There isn't a parameter for the minimum double-click time.

Of course, I can't prove there isn't an undocumented parameter, but if there was a documented parameter it would almost certainly be documented in `SystemParametersInfo`.